# IOError on csv load in Python 2

Tags: python, csv, anaconda, ioerror

I'm trying to load a csv into Phython 2 using Anaconda with the following code:

```
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\thakuar1\Desktop\Machine_Learning\at_LoanStats3a_20170620_v12.csv')
```

but keep running into the below error:

```
IOError: File C:\Users  hakuar1\Desktop\Machine_Learningt_LoanStats3a_20170620_v12.csv does not exist
```

Any reason why the filepath would be dropping characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Any reason why the filepath would be dropping characters?

`\t` stands for a TAB space, be sure to escape that string by writing it with double slash `\\`, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) to know more about escaping characters.

Comment: Great! Then you should accept this answer, so other users know this was the solution. Also, remember to upvote of you found this useful

Answer (score 0):

The back slash is an escape character. The best approach is to build the path with the os.path module since it will work across different OSs. But you can simply use a raw string to ignore escape characters.

`pd.read_csv(r'...')`

Comment: I tried the double back slash instead and that worked. I will try this also and see if this does the job too. Thanks!